# DIV Expanding Unexpectedly

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem with some of my code right now. I'm currently creating a navigation bar for a web page. Kind of like those that run across horizontaly across the screen. But my problem is that my navigation bar apparently has a really large height, disabling access to the content below it.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head> head.... <head>
    <body>
    <div id="nav_bar><ul><li><div class="nav_box"></div></li>..More LIs...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

nav_bar is positioned absolute with a top value. nav_box is usually hidden, and expands using css when hovered over a li.
If you need anything, just comment. Thanks!

Comment: The UL has a display of 'inline'.

Comment: Please do not reply, I have found a 'crummy' way to fix this.

Comment: Answer your question and mark it!

Answer (score 0):

It needn't be 'crummy' (p tags?), just give your body a margin-top equal to the height of the .nav_bar

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use max-height to fix this little 'bug'. At first, it was a very bad way, and it had a bug of it's own. But since I was using CSS animations, I remembered that the max-height property can be animated. So I just had to give my navigation bar the ability for it's max-height property to be animated, and it worked like a charm.